# How does GitHub Conduit launch itself at startup?

Tags: macos, launchd

A program called GitHub Conduit (part of [GitHub for Mac](https://mac.github.com/)) runs in the background on my computer. If I kill it, `launchd` restarts it.

The `launchd` manpage lists every location in which it looks for jobs at startup:

```
$ man launchd
[snip]
FILES
     ~/Library/LaunchAgents         Per-user agents provided by the user.
     /Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the adminis-
                                    trator.
     /Library/LaunchDaemons         System-wide daemons provided by the admin-
                                    istrator.
     /System/Library/LaunchAgents   Per-user agents provided by Mac OS X.
     /System/Library/LaunchDaemons  System-wide daemons provided by Mac OS X.
```

I checked each of these folders, and **GitHub conduit doesn't have a file in any of them**. I also checked Users & Groups preferences, and it's not listed in my login items.

FWIW, `launchctl list com.github.GitHub.Conduit` outputs this:

```
{
    "Label" = "com.github.GitHub.Conduit";
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "Aqua";
    "OnDemand" = true;
    "LastExitStatus" = 15;
    "PID" = 596;
    "TimeOut" = 30;
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/usr/libexec/launchproxyls";
        "com.github.GitHub.Conduit";
    );
    "EnableTransactions" = true;
    "MachServices" = {
        "com.github.GitHub.Conduit" = mach-port-object;
    };
    "PerJobMachServices" = {
        "com.apple.CFPasteboardClient" = mach-port-object;
        "com.apple.tsm.portname" = mach-port-object;
        "com.apple.axserver" = mach-port-object;
    };
};
```

### Question

What makes `launchd` start GitHub Conduit at startup and how could I stop it if I wanted to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it! In OS X 10.11, the preference is stored here:

```
/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/loginitems.{uid}.plist
```

For me, that file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.github.GitHub.Conduit</key>
    <string>com.github.GitHub</string>
    <key>version.com.github.GitHub.Conduit</key>
    <string>161</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

I, too, was surprised to discover this process running. It seems to be a webserver installed by the github app. It doesn't seem to be possible to stop it and continue to use github.

> When you run GitHub for Mac, it automatically launches Conduit and tells Mac OS X to keep it alive. Thus, if Conduit crashes or you terminate it with Activity Monitor or kill, it will relaunch, even if GitHub for Mac is not running.

Details [here](https://help.github.com/articles/github-conduit/). I have asked about security of this feature at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/844877/github-for-mac-installs-a-webserver-github-conduit-is-that-a-security-risk).